# I want add picture in GridView tooltip before open

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I create in XAML RadGridVieaw controls custom tooltip and when tool tip before opening, I want read row and take ID and then load picture from database.

1 step I create custom tool tip

```
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:GridViewRow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource GridViewRowStyle}" >
                      <Setter Property="ToolTipService.IsEnabled" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadGridView}}}" />
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" >
                    <Setter.Value>
        <ToolTip ToolTipService.ShowDuration="1000000" >
        <Grid > 
        <Border HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="170" Margin="5,0,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" BorderBrush="#FFCED8DA" BorderThickness="1" Padding="1">
    <Image  x:Name="GeneralTabItem_EmployeeImage" Source="{Binding CRAPhotoPhoto, Converter={StaticResource BinaryArrayToURIConverter}}"  Stretch="UniformToFill"
    Width="120" Height="160"/>
       </Border>
       <Grid/>
 <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="ExtnedPrisonerInfoView_DataInput_ListGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ToolTipService.ShowDuration="100000000"
                    DataContext="{Binding ''}" ToolTipOpening="OnContentChanged">

        </telerik:RadGridView>
```

2 step I want to code behind catch event opening Tool tip.

3 step attach picture to the opening tool tip Image  in Name="GeneralTabItem_EmployeeImage"

Please help me ToolTipOpening event is not working.

Comment: What exactly is your issue? What does "not working" mean here? What did you try?

Comment: ToolTipOpening="Method" event not called

Comment: There are non-closed tags here. Therefore, this xaml code does not reproduce the problem. Where did you wire up the event? Please, provide a complete, reproductible code.

Comment: <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="ExtnedPrisonerInfoView_DataInput_ListGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ToolTipService.ShowDuration="100000000"
                    DataContext="{Binding ''}" ToolTipOpening="OnContentChanged">

        </telerik:RadGridView>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as far as the event handler is concerned:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:GridViewRow}"  BasedOn="{StaticResource GridViewRowStyle}" >
    <EventSetter Event="ToolTipOpening" Handler="outerGrid_ToolTipOpening" />
    ...
```

But if you want to do something with the `Image` in the `ToolTip`, you need to wait until it has been created. You might as well handle the `Loaded` event of the `Image` and set the `Source` of it in there:

```
private void GeneralTabItem_EmployeeImage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Image img = sender as Image;
    //set source...
}
```

XAML:

```
<Setter Property="ToolTip" >
    <Setter.Value>
        <ToolTip ToolTipService.ShowDuration="1000000">
            <Grid>
                <Border HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="170" Margin="5,0,0,0" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" BorderBrush="#FFCED8DA" BorderThickness="1" Padding="1">
                    <Image x:Name="GeneralTabItem_EmployeeImage" Stretch="UniformToFill"
                           Width="120" Height="160"
                           Loaded="GeneralTabItem_EmployeeImage_Loaded"/>
                </Border>
                <Grid/>
            </Grid>
        </ToolTip>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Obviously you won't be able to set the `Source` property of an `Image` that resides in a `ToolTip` *before* the ToolTip has been opened because by then there is no `Image`. So this doesn't make much sense.

Comment: When choose Loaded="GeneralTabItem_EmployeeImage_Loaded" accure error:
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid'.

Answer (score 1):

Create a simple tooltip first:

```
<Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource 
  GridViewRowStyle}">
  <Setter Property="ToolTip">
      <Setter.Value>
          <ToolTip>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding EmployeeName}"></TextBlock>
           </ToolTip>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Verify that works and if it does start adding more complex things like converters and ToolTipService stuff one at a time to see what is it exactly that is invalidating your XAML because XAML error is the only reason why the event would not be firing...